What does で済ませる mean in this sentence⁇
I found this sentence in a book.
いつも夕食は簡単な料理やスーパーのおそうざいで済ませている
And this is the translation:
My dinner is always something simple or some side dish I bought at the supermarket.
I get that they probably paraphrased the translation but I still don't understand it. Why there's で before 済ませている?
Thank youu

済ます is used in unexpected ways that can be hard to translate literally.

いつも夕食は簡単な料理やスーパーのおそうざいで済ませている


For dinner, I always make do with a simple dish and some side from the grocery.

Here 済ませる has the meaning of "to make do with" and the idea of "with" is captured by the particle で.
I said it's hard to translate because this notion of "to make do with" seems to be more broadly applied in Japanese than feels natural in English.  In English, "to make do with" can sound a bit like a hardship, but in Japanese, such a connotation does seem to be as strongly present if present at all.

Did you mean "... doesn't seem to be ..."?

@aguijonazo I'm not sure what I actually meant now that I look at it again.  But somehow, I feel with "to make do with" there are potential negative connotations.  I didn't feel like that's the case with 済ます.  Perhaps I'm wrong?
